# How to write a mango filter on the size of an array?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-mango

I would like to find documents with a mango query by specifying the minimal and maximal size of an array property. Given a document with an array property `customers`. I'd like to be able to find all documents with the number of customers between 10 and 20.

Something like

```
mango_query = {
  "doc.customers": {"$size": {"gte": 10}},
  "doc.customers": {"$size": {"lte": 20}}
}
```

The response to a request like that is

```
Bad argument for operator $size: {[{<<36,108,116,101>>,10}]}')
```

So how should I write a mango filter on the size of an array?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the code [here](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/main/src/mango/src/mango_selector.erl#L146), only integer argument is supported for $size operator. So it can't be combined with other operators. It supports only $size exact matches.

```
norm_ops({[{<<"$size">>, Arg}]}) when is_integer(Arg), Arg >= 0 ->
    {[{<<"$size">>, Arg}]};
norm_ops({[{<<"$size">>, Arg}]}) ->
    ?MANGO_ERROR({bad_arg, '$size', Arg});
```

And when matching

```
match({[{<<"$size">>, Arg}]}, Values, _Cmp) when is_list(Values) ->
    length(Values) == Arg;
match({[{<<"$size">>, _}]}, _Value, _Cmp) ->
    false;
```

`length(Values) == Arg` Only exact match is supported

Comment: Do you know if an appropriate integer field can be generated on the fly? I tried `"doc.customers.length": {"gte": 10}` and `"doc.customers.$size": {"gte": 10}` without success

Comment: This behaviour is not supported by CouchDB. I think you should try to query using views. On the view map function you can compute this value.

Comment: As an additional comment... operators start by $. This would be the correct way "doc.customers.length": {"$gte": 10} but it will not work as it is not supported.

Comment: Do you think it is feasible to create a PR with two new operators `"$sizeLte"` and `"$sizeGte"`? How long would it take until these operators are realsed?

Comment: https://github.com/hklarner/couchdb-mango/commit/e519f224423ca4696a61d0065530103dd8c6651b